# Can you Misty Step to a location Familiar sees

Tags: dnd-5e, familiars

Misty Step states that its range is limited by vision:

> You teleport up to 30 feet to an unoccupied space that you can see.

Find Familiar states that you can "see" through the Familiar's eyes:

> Additionally, as an action, you can see through your familiar's eyes and hear what it hears until the start of your next turn, gaining the benefits of any special senses that the familiar has... PHB. 240

Does this mean you can teleport to any location your Familiar can see that is in range? Or is the "you" in Misty Step strictly limited to your actual person? What is the precedent for this type of vision based specification?

Note: this is not related to the question of line of effect. Which is relevant, but of course, the Familiar has a separate line of sight from itself to the location you see. This question is just about whether the Familiar meets the criteria as *your vision*.

Comment: Hello and welcome to RPG.SE! Please take the [tour] if you haven't already done so and we've got the [help] and comments here if you have some questions or need further guidance. It looks like your question has been closed as a duplicate of another question, this means your question has effectively been asked before and you can hopefully find an answer in the question. Of note, this isn't a bad thing at all, in fact, it helps people find that question more easily. Thar said, if you feel your question *isn't* answered, feel free to [edit] or leave a comment. Your question can always be reopened